# Extract decimal separator

Tags: c#, string, internationalization, decimal

I'm importing a csv file in C#, sometimes with '.', sometimes with ',' as decimal separator.

Is there a best way of determinate the decimal separator better than counting from the last char down to the first apperance?

Thanks in advance.

Franklin Albricias.

Comment: When ',' is the decimal separator, how are the actual values separated?

Comment: using commas as decimal separators in a 'comma separated value' file must complicate things. Does it mean that numbers have to be enclosed in quotes? ... or are we talking generic csv which doesn't use commas to separate?

Comment: To Kyle:

The user creates the csv file. There are Spanish and English users.

Comment: To Artelius:

In Spain, the default decimal separator is ',', with the point '.' as a thousand separator.

Comment: To Pavium:

Actually I have ';' separated values in the file, not ','.

Comment: To Artelius: sorry, I didn't understand you in my quick reading: the values are ";" separated.

Comment: Yes, I've heard of csv files which actually use TABs to separate values. Using ';' seems, if anything, more logical than TABs, and it would be crazy to call it a 'semicolon separated value' file. I should have realised all this when I saw your name. Silly me.

Answer (score 6):

If you know the correct culture in advance (for example, because you know the user that created the file), you can try to parse the provided value using the appropriate `CultureInfo` or `NumberFormatInfo`:

```
Decimal value = Decimal.Parse(input, new CultureInfo("es-ES"));
```

But if the type is not known in advance, you'll have to check it manually by examining the characters until you find a separator. (And even that approach assumes that you are guaranteed to always have a decimal separator, such that `one` is written as `1.0` rather than `1`.)

You can't just try each expected format one after the other because you may get false positives.

`10,000` means something *valid* but *different* for both formats.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use both as a separator?

Have a look at [NumberFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx)

**Edit:**
For each value try to parse it with one of the separators.
If that fails try to parse it with the other.

Comment: Then how do you tell which commas separate values, and which commas separate fractioal parts of numbers?

Comment: It's not my decision, it's the user one. Some users will export from Excel with ',' some will do it with '.'.

That's why I need to detect the decimal separator.

Comment: You probably can't. Not 100% anyway. Unless the values are enclosed in quotes or something else.

Comment: Or the value separator is not comma.

Comment: Ok thank you, NumberFormatInfo.GetDecimalSeparator will do it!

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the actual data stored in the csv file and the data separation character (';' or ',' or ' ').

If all data is always in floting point notation you can use a regular expression that checks both cases. You can use `"d+,\d+"` to check for values separated by `','` or `"\d+\.\d+"` for values using `'.'` as separator

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that the file contains only numbers - no strings and what ever - and there are at least two columns, you can do the following.

Go through the first line and look for a semicolon. If you find one, you have semicolon separated numbers with commas as decimal separator, else comma separated numbers with points as decimal separator.

In all other cases you will have to use a heuristic (and sometimes get the wrong conclusion) or you have to strictly parse the file under both assumptions.